# Bootstrap navbar and ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am having an issue with routing to a view using ui-router on bootstrap 3. I cannot seem to bring the third view, "**Bitcoin**", on the navbar menu (hamburger icon). I would like to bring the template (*bitcoin.html*) below the navbar when clicked on "Bitcoin". What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help in advance.

[Plunker example][1]

Comment: Plunker : [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wNMdPk3RXk1J9sH08VUF?p=options)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out. The view was coming below the iframe. I'll need to restructure the code. Thanks.